# How to set waitSeconds for requirejs in amber?

Tags: smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

I created a project using Amber Smalltalk and hosted it on a remote server so multiple people can access it. The network connection is slow and it triggers timeout and just figured that the setting 'waitSeconds' solves the problem.

But, we can't figure out where to set it.The config.js file is generated, and can't be changed manually. Only managed to change it in the default settings in the requirejs source. But that should not be the right place. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`config.js` is generated using https://lolg.it/herby/amd-config-builder

from the readme:

> The `local.amd.json` files describe the `require.config` part for the module at the directory where they are present.

to add `WaitSeconds` to `config.js` add it to `local.amd.json` at the root level of your project.